# Is redis transaction (WATCH, MULTI ,EXEC ) possible over multiplexed connection?

Tags: redis, transactions

I am using Redis library that offers Connection multiplexing (I am currently using the Rust lib , but I think the question is relevant for any implementation).

According to the what I've read about [multiplexing](https://redis.com/blog/multiplexing-explained/) (And also what I understand from the lib implementation) , It utilizes the same connection for handling db operations from multiple contexts (threads/tasks/etc..).

Now, I'm not sure what will happened if [WATCH](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) is called in parallel with 2 different contexts on the same multiplexed-connection. Will the EXEC from one context cancel the WATCH in the other thread, or maybe Redis somehow knows how to distinguish between contexts even though they're utilizing the same connection?

Comment: which client are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible over multiplexed connection. The Redis transaction context is attached to a specific "client" meaning a specific conneciton.